# IgnoreProperty and Reveal.Member on Fluent NHibernate 1.1.0.685 on component type

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I'm trying to ignore the property which is a ReadOnlyCollection and map the private property. I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find a setter for property 'MyCollection' in class 'Project.Core.MyClass'
```

This is the automapper for that class which is a component.

```
mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.MyCollection);
mapping.HasMany<CollectionObject>(Reveal.Member<MyClass>("myCollection")).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

Hope someone can help me on this one.